# Unique and Unmodifiable system information to use to identify a PC?

Tags: licensing, operating-system

I need create licences for a number of computers. The license should be created from pieces of information that come from the PC.

I've already got BIOS ID and Windows serial number.
What else can i use?

Comment: This may give you some ideas: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx

Comment: I would really consider NOT doing software licences. It is false to believe software licences like this will have any effect what so ever. Do yourself a favor and forget about it and spend time on something that is worth working on instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want. HDD Serial Number, Main-Board Serial, CPU ID, and so on.

You could even use a "hardlock" (hardware key, like a parallel key or USB key, or even make your own hardlock using a basic prototype board. There is virtually no limit! And if someone set's himself to bypass the license system, they probably will succeed, no matter how hard is your licensing system.

The best option I belive to be is to use pick a few numbers form the hardware, then apply an encryption algorithm over those numbers (try not to use known hashes), and generate the license based on that. But be sure that at some point it will be "more or less a waste of time".